# canvas.toDataURL() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, canvas

I am currently working on improving/fixing an image upload web application for the company I work for.
However I have run into a small snag that I have not been able to fix.

The issue is that sometimes the toDataURL() does not work, it does not format the image in the right way, leaving me with an empty image box. Even though the [data-canvas-id] tag contains data, the .toDataURL() still seems to fail in its reformatting.

The following function is meant to find the canvas and the image inside its upload queue, set the height and width and reformat the image to the img.src

'id' is the image name.

```
function getImageInfoFromCanvas(id) {
  var can = $('[data-canvas-id="' + id + '"]').find('canvas');
  var ctx = can[0].getContext('2d');
  var height = can.attr('height');
  var width = can.attr('width');

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = can[0].toDataURL();

  return { "imageStr": img.outerHTML, "width": width, "height": height };
}
```

The area in the HTML where it is taking its canvas data from, looks like this

```
<td>
  <strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong>
  <div data-canvas-id="{{ item.file.name }}" class="active" ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-thumb="{ file: item._file }">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</td>
```

The img.src when reformatted is supposed to be hundreds of lines long (Checked with a console log)

I have also noticed that when it toDataURL() fails the width and height does not get set properly either

So when the images does not get reformatted properly, this is all it sends back. Which is basically a empty square.

> data:image/png;base64,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

I have looked around at other posts to see if I could find a solution to my problem, but those ones that matched my problem. Have never gotten an answer

Comment: You do not show any code regarding adding context (pixels) to the canvas. `toDataURL` is reliable and will always create a data URL that accurately reflects the content of the canvas, if you are getting unexpected result that means that the canvas does not contain the expected content. The problem is not toDataURL. If rendering an image, ensure that the image has loaded before you render it to the canvas, Failure to do so is a common reason why the canvas sometimes has content and sometimes not (image load time can vary and if cached can load in time to render)

Comment: @Blindman67 I've recently cycled back to this issue at work, after working on a few other projects that my boss deemed more important. I have now spend some time trying to figure out how I could best work around making sure that the canvas with the image is properly loaded before trying to work with the image. I was wondering if you might have some ideas?